# How to set one of a series of default values via conditionalPanel?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a numericInput that, based on a selectInput, should take one of four distinct inputs as a default value. The expected behavior is that you drop down the selectInput and the conditional panel populates with the appropriate value. Instead, it seems that the hidden panels are still passing variables and the behavior seems unpredictable, favoring the first panel.

Is there maybe a multiple condition version?

```
selectInput("type",label=strong("Model Type"),
            choices = list(One="1",
            Two="2",
            Three="3",
            Four="4")),

            conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.type == '1'",
            numericInput("numGroups",label=strong("Num Groups"),value=10))
             ,              
            conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.type == '2'",
            numericInput("numGroups",label=strong("Num Groups"),value=20))
            ,
            conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.type == '3'",
            numericInput("numGroups",label=strong("Num Groups"),value=30))
            ,
            conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.type == '4'",
            numericInput("numGroups",label=strong("Num Groups"),value=40))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your inputs have the same ID. Why not have one `numericInput`, then update its value if the selected value changes?

For example, in `ui.R`:

```
shinyUI(basicPage(
  selectInput("type",label=strong("Model Type"),
              choices = list(One="1",
                             Two="2",
                             Three="3",
                             Four="4")),
  numericInput("numGroups", label=strong("Num Groups"), 0)
))
```

Then in `server.R`:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    new.val <- switch(input$type, "1"=10, "2"=20, "3"=30, "4"=40)   
    updateNumericInput(session, "numGroups", value=new.val)
  })
})
```

Comment: This only works if the numericInput values correspond to the group labels, no? That isn't actually the case, a bad example on my part. Updated.

Comment: As is, yes, but you could apply some logic within `observe`. I'll update.

Comment: This works. As a shiny newbie I had no idea about the update* functions in general. Thanks!